# Show banner only on archive pages using PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header

I have a banner I would like to only show on archive pages on my website. I can't figure out the php code to do so. Here is what I have so far (obviously I've removed a lot of the code to make this look cleaner and easier):

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header navbar-static-top fixed-top <?php echo wp_bootstrap_starter_bg_class(); ?>" role="banner">
</header>

<?php if(is_archive()) ?>

<div class="free-shipping-banner">
    <p>
        FREE SHIPPING on all print orders within North America.
    </p>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can see it is my free-shipping-banner that I want only displayed on archive pages. I'm not getting any errors with this code, but it's still showing up on all other pages of my website. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your correct code. Please add brackets for if statement.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header navbar-static-top fixed-top <?php echo wp_bootstrap_starter_bg_class(); ?>" role="banner">
</header>

<?php if(is_archive()) {  ?>

<div class="free-shipping-banner">
    <p>
        FREE SHIPPING on all print orders within North America.
    </p>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

The mistake in your code is that the if statement will only look for the next line. But when you place brackets; you tell the server where it ends. You used endif but you also forgot a colon at the end of if statement. The above code will work.